# XPathNodeIterator over an array of XPathNavigable objects?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, iterator

I have an array of objects that are IXpathNavigable. I want to access the array through an xsl extention object, so I should probably do that by using an XPathNodeIterator. But how do I properly create the NodeIterator so that it iterates over the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `XPathNodeIterator` from `IXPathNavigator.Select` and related methods.

However if you create your own implementation (subclass) of `XPathNodeIterator` you could then create it in any way you like.